# OSX Terminal.app SSH port

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I feel like a complete dunce - but I cannot seem to connect with Terminal.app and SSH to a non-standard SSH port. I'm on Mountain Lion.

I've tried all of the following:

```
$ ssh myuser@mysite.com -p 42586
$ ssh myuser@mysite.com -p42586
$ ssh -p 42586 myuser@mysite.com
$ ssh -p42586 myuser@mysite.com
```

I cannot seem to get the syntax right, all of the above produce an error. What is the correct order of flags? I have checked the `man` page and it shows it as preceding the [user]@[domain] section, however, this throws an error as well.

**Edit:**

More information and raw terminal output:

```
$ ssh mysite.com -p42586
--hangs--
$ ssh mysite.com -p 42586
--hangs--
$ ssh -p42586 mysite.com
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
$ ssh -p 42586 mysite.com
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
/usr/bin/ssh: option requires an argument -- p
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
```

Examples 1 and 2 hang until timeout. 3 and 4 produce a grep usage echo as well as an ssh usage echo.

**Edit 2:**

Thanks for the suggestion @topguncoder my original attempt was the colon notation - but that produces a different error:

```
$ ssh myuser@mysite.com:42586
ssh: Could not resolve hostname mysite:42586: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: not sure about this but have you tried:
ssh myuser@mysite.com:42586

Comment: What's the error on Terminal?

Comment: Updated the question to provide some more information

Comment: Try adding the `-v` flag to get more output from `ssh` about what it is doing. The first two examples seem to be working, but there isn't anything responding at port 42586 on the remote side. The fact that you get usage messages for `grep` on the other two is... odd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
"ssh" -p 42586 mysite.com
```

to ignore your `alias` settings. It looks like you might have `ssh` aliased to something else. If this works, you should check your `.profile` for any `ssh` aliases.

Comment: OP: for confirmation, what is the output of `type ssh`?

Comment: Output of type ssh: `ssh is aliased to ~/bin/safe_ssh '`

Comment: Any thoughts about how to maintain the alias and pipe the flags into the alias?

Comment: Did you perchance use this script? http://www.sipfish.com/blog/automatically-change-command-line-colors-when-using-ssh/ You'll have to fix the script to skip command-line arguments.

Comment: @nneonneo That's *precisely* what's happening - completely forgot about it and feel like a double-dunce.

Comment: It seems that this script expects you to use `ssh [options] user@host` notation, since it splits on the `@` symbol. So, try `ssh -p 42586 yourname@mysite.com` and see if that works.

Comment: Yeah I tried that - still doesn't work. But I appreciate the feedback - I haven't used the color coding for a while anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that on your system, the `ssh` command somehow was redefined as the `grep` command. Try this:

```
alias | /usr/bin/grep ssh
```

What do you see? Also, try this:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -p 42586 myuser@mysite.com
```

Do you have a success connection? If ssh was aliased into something else. Check the following files:

- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.profile

You can then remove the alias, or use the absolute path (e.g `/usr/bin/ssh`)